# Android checkboxes, how to implement if statement.

Tags: android, if-statement, checkbox, count

I am currently coding an android app but I encountered some difficulty.
I am able to receive some checkbox values from another activity using the `getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean()`function.

But my question is, how can i make sure that checkboxes with the characters 'wb' or 'ab' or 'alb' together with(or not) 'cs' appearing, a count is performed and the one with the greatest value between 'wb', 'ab' and 'alb' is chosen and a summary is displayed via a texfield.

e.g. if there appearances of 'wb' are greater than those of 'alb' and ab, then the result is displayed "you have a widened bronchus".

```
package com.example.vic.cdmes_;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class results extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button displayResult;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    viewResults();

}

private void viewResults() {
    final Boolean wb1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb1");
    final Boolean wb2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb2");
    final Boolean wb3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb3");
    final Boolean wb4 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb4");
    final Boolean wb5 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb5");
    final Boolean wb6 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb6");
    final Boolean wb7 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb7");
    final Boolean cs1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("cs1");
    final Boolean cs2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("cs2");
    final Boolean vb1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("vb1");
    final Boolean vb2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("vb2");
    final Boolean vb3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("vb3");
    final Boolean vb4 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("vb4");
    final Boolean vb5 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("vb5");
    final Boolean alb1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("alb1");
    final Boolean alb2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("alb2");
    final Boolean alb3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("alb3");
    final Boolean ab1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ab1");
    final Boolean ab2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ab2");
    final Boolean ab3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ab3");
    final Boolean ab4 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ab4");

    displayResult = (Button)findViewById(R.id.displayResults);
    displayResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(results.this,.toString(),
              //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(wb1&&wb2&&wb3&&wb4&&wb5&&wb6&&wb7&&cs1&&cs2)
            {
                //if the number of checkboxes exceeds
            }
            else
                if (vb1&&vb2&&vb3&&vb4&&vb5&&cs1&&cs2)
                {
                    //display the person might be having a widened bronchus
                }
                else
                if (alb1&&alb2&&alb3&&cs1&&cs2)
                {
                    //display the person might be having a alb disease
                }
                else
                if (ab1&&ab2&&ab3&&ab4&&cs1&&cs2)
                {
                    //display the person might be having a airborne disease
                }

        }
    });
}
```

}

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you want the count of wb, alb and ab right?

Comment: Yes I do @Venilla

Comment: Have you tried the second answer which was posted by me

Comment: Yes, I am currently working on it @Venilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Default Boolean value.  Like This

```
 final Boolean wb1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb1",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of wb, ab and alb below, using that you can write the if statement.

```
int wbCount = 0,  abCount = 0, albCount = 0;
boolean cs = (cs1 && cs2);

        for(int i=1; i <= 7; i++) {
            if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("wb"+i) && cs) {
                wbCount++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
            if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("alb"+i) && cs) {
                albCount++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=1; i <= 4; i++) {
            if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ab"+i) && cs) {
                abCount++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. this will greatly help

Comment: I've found this helpful. @Vennila. {}

Comment: no probs. Pls vote for this answer if you got the result. Thank you.

Comment: @Venilla, i have tried it but it is not doing anything. No action is visible :(